# Extracting null fields in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I will try to be as detailed as possible.  Our corporate controller has asked me for some information regarding our suppliers.  Here are the tables:

`spp` = supplier table, each supplier has one record, there are 5,222 records
`ast` = supplier account profile, there is a (M, 1) relationship between this table and spp, there are 8,950 records in this table.  Each duplicate spp_id has a different atp_id which is a transaction profile.
`crt` = bank account information, a supplier may or may not have bank account info
`xvd` = table of checking tables, xvd.xcd_id is the field that holds the checking table id.  Checking table 0007 is the table that contains the discount info.

Here is my script:

```
select spp.spp_id supp_num,
   spp.spp_matchname supp_name,
   case when spp.spp_ddcalculation = 0 
       then 'End of Month' 
       else
       case when spp.spp_ddcalculation = 1 
           then 'Net' 
           else
           case when spp.spp_ddcalculation = 2 
               then 'End of 10, 20, 30' 
               else 
               case when spp.spp_ddcalculation = 3
                   then 'End of 15 or 30'
                   else null
               end 
           end 
       end 
   end calculation1,                                              
   convert(varchar(2), spp.spp_ddduration) + case when spp.spp_ddmd = 0 
                                                 then ' Days' 
                                                 else case when spp.spp_ddmd = 1
                                                     then ' Months'
                                                     else null
                                                 end 
                                             end duration1,
   spp.spp_ddday stop_day1,
   xvd.xvd_desc discount,
   crt.crt_name bank,
   case when ast.ast_ddcalculation = 0 
       then 'End of Month' 
       else
       case when ast.ast_ddcalculation = 1 
           then 'Net' 
           else
           case when ast.ast_ddcalculation = 2 
               then 'End of 10, 20, 30' 
               else case when ast.ast_ddcalculation = 3
                   then 'End of 15 or 30' 
                   else null
               end
           end 
       end 
   end     
   calculation2,
   convert(varchar(2), ast.ast_ddduration) + case when ast.ast_ddmd = 0 
                                                 then ' Days' 
                                                 else case when ast.ast_ddmd = 1
                                                     then ' Months'
                                                     else null
                                                 end 
                                             end                            
   duration2,
   ast.ast_ddday stop_day2

from spp left join ast on spp.spp_id = ast.spp_id
     left join crt on ast.crt_id = crt.crt_id
     inner join xvd on ast.cfd_id = xvd.xcv_id 

where xvd.xcd_id = '0007'
    and xvd.lng_id = 0

order by spp.spp_id
```

The problem is that there are 371 records in the ast table that have a non null cfd_id which is the field that relates to the discount in checking table 0007.  When I run this I get 371 records, but I need all suppliers, even those with null discounts.  I know the problem is a combination of my joins and the fact that there is not a null xcv_id in checking table 0007.  Can anyone see anything glaring that I have overlooked?

To recap, there are 8,950 records in ast, but only 371 of them have a non null cfd_id.  I need to grab all 8,950 records, I can't seem to extract the null discounts.  I think I can probably pull everything into a temp table then grab the discounts, but am wondering if there is a way to do this in one select statement.

Thanks

Tony

Edit:  The last line of my from statement seems to be the primary issue
`inner join xvd on ast.cfd_id = xvd.xcv_id`

There are no null xcv_id but there are null cfd_id.  Is there another way to join those two tables, besides checking for equality?

Forgot to mention, we are on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just change your inner join to a left join:

```
from spp left join ast on spp.spp_id = ast.spp_id 
left join crt on ast.crt_id = crt.crt_id  
inner join xvd on ast.cfd_id = xvd.xcv_id
```

to

```
from spp left join ast on spp.spp_id = ast.spp_id 
left join crt on ast.crt_id = crt.crt_id 
left join xvd on ast.cfd_id = xvd.xcv_id
```

If you are saying that you want to select records where `xvd.xcd_id` is `0007` or `null` then change your where clause to this:

```
(xvd.xcd_id = '0007' OR xvd.xcd_id is null)
```

Comment: Thanks, already tried that, sorry I should have stated that.  I originally had all inner joins, then thought they should all be left joins so I switched them.  It makes perfect sense to me that they should all be left joins but I am still only getting 371 records and no null discounts.

Comment: did you change your where clause as well (the last code sample I have)?  If you don't have that you are essentially making your `left join` an `inner join`

Comment: I did change the where clause, but the xcd_id field is not the null field I need.  The xcd_id will be '0007'.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve the problem ?

```
FROM   spp
   LEFT JOIN ast
     ON spp.spp_id = ast.spp_id
   LEFT JOIN crt
     ON ast.crt_id = crt.crt_id
   INNER JOIN xvd
     ON xvd.xcv_id = ast.cfd_id
WHERE  xvd.xcd_id = '0007'
   AND xvd.lng_id = 0
```

Comment: No, it does not, still 371 records.

Comment: What happens of you change the middle JOIN to RIGHT JOIN ?

Comment: Then I only get the 15 records that have a non null ast.crt_id

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect use for views. Instead of trying to build one complex query, you could build a series of views that build upon one another filtering the data the way you want it... then apply the final query to the last view.

Comment: I have thought about that as well as selecting into a temporary table then adding the discount field, the problem is that whether I make a query, create a table, or create a view, I still need to create a relationship back to checking table 0007.  The only way to relate the entities is by checking for equality between cfd_id in the supplier entity and xcv_id in the checking table.  If I do that, then when cfd_id is null and there is no null in xcv_id, that record is not included and there are 4,851 suppliers with no discount (null cfd_id).